# Component is specific class - does not work in BPL structure

Tags: delphi, rtti, delphi-11-alexandria, bpl

I am upgrading Delphi software from Delphi 6 (2001) to Delphi 11 Alexandria.

This software consists of many BPL's, but this code is not working properly. The [is command](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.php?Name=is#:%7E:text=Delphi%20Basics%20%3A%20is%20command&text=The%20Is%20keyword%20is%20used,TButton%2C%20or%20TList%20or%20whatever.) is not returning True, when checking if the component from a BPL is an TIBQuery - although it really is.

```pascal
    procedure LoadDLLAndPassDatabaseConnection(const DLLName: string);
    var
      PackageHandle: HMODULE;
      ServiceModule: TMyServiceModule;
      I: Integer;
      Component: TComponent;
    begin
      PackageHandle := LoadPackage(PChar(DLLName));
      ServiceModule := TMyServiceModule(GetProcAddress(hInst,'GetServiceModule'));

      if Assigned(ServiceModule) then
      begin
        for I:=0 to ServiceModule.ComponentCount - 1 do
        begin
          Component := ServiceModule.Components[I];

          // This component is declared in another bpl.
          // It really is an TIBQuery, but the following if never returns True...
          // (Evaluating Component.ClassName results in 'TIBQuery')
          if Component is TIBQuery then
          begin
            // this is never executed...
            TIBQuery(Component).Database := GetDatabase;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
```

I already considered to compare classnames, but this does not work for descendants. And we tried toggling project options such as "Emit runtime type information", but that's not making any difference.

How to get this working?

Thank you!

Comment: There is no "Delphi XE 11", last XE version was ```Delphi XE 8```!

Comment: You load bpl dynamically and seems that you got 2 registration in rtti of same class. Ensure that target bpl using runtime linking to BPL with class TIBQuery and your exe-project(or bpl with this checking) using runtime linking to same bpl. When you use huge BPL structure of project does not allow warning like "unit implicitly imported into package...". If it's your unit - add it into project, if it's not - add correct bpl into requires section.

Answer (score 3):

The `is` operator does not work across BPLs (DLLs) for the following reason:

- The class you are inspecting is implemented inside its own unit file.
- You build the BPL, link the unit, and a RTTI section is created inside the BPL file.
- Then, you build the EXE, link the unit, and a **new** RTTI section is created inside the EXE file.

**Now:** the `class name` is the same for the two modules, but the RTTI, used by the `is` operator to check equality, **are different**, so the operator returns **FALSE**!

**Solution:** check equality againts class name.

Comment: And - if needed - traverse upwards in the class hierarchy to also handle descendant classes...

Comment: @HeartWare I guess you mean '... to handle ancestor classes'.

Comment: @TomBrunberg: Depends on whether you're looking from the POV of the IS *target* (right side) or the IS *source* (left side)...

Comment: Oh dear! ......

Comment: "*The `is` operator does not work across BPLs (DLLs)*" - not across DLLs, no.  But it is *supposed* to work across BPLs, but only if the target class is implemented in a sparate runtime package that both BPL and EXE share.

Answer (score 3):

I found this somewhere, but it seems to contradict Antionio's answer a bit.

> When you use packages, there is only ever one copy of any unit in
> memory. One copy of Forms, one copy of SysUtils, one copy of System
> (well, most of it), one copy of StdCtrls, etc.
> All class-related operations, such as the "is" and "as" operators, rely
> on class references. Class references are actually just addresses. They
> point to definitions for the layouts of the classes' internals. (They
> point to what's called the virtual-method table, the VMT.) Two classes
> are the same if they point to the same VMT -- if the addresses are equal.
> When you have a class defined in the EXE's copy of StdCtrls and the same
> class defined in a DLL's copy of StdCtrls, those classes will really
> have different addresses. The "is" and "as" operators won't work with
> cross-module clases. But when you use packages, there is only one copy
> of the class, kept in vcl70.bpl, so all modules that reference that
> package will share a single class definition.

Comment: This is a very good pojnt, but it's a comment to another answer rather than an answer in its own right

Answer (score 0):

As Antonio Petricca wrote (thank you!), it's not possible to use the `is` operator. I now have implemented this by comparing (ancestor) class names - I want to share the code:

```
function IsSameClassOrAncestor(const ClazzToCheck: TClass; const Clazz: TClass): Boolean;
begin
  Result := SameText(ClazzToCheck.ClassName, Clazz.ClassName);
  if not Result and not SameText(ClazzToCheck.ClassName, 'TObject') then
  begin
    Result := IsSameClassOrAncestor(ClazzToCheck.ClassParent, Clazz);
  end;
end;
```

This way, I can check this as follows:

```
if IsSameClassOrAncestor(Component, TIBQuery)
begin
  // The code is now executed correctly, also for descendants
  TIBQuery(Component).Database := GetDatabase;
end;
```

Comment: Perhaps you want to use the name `IsSameClassOrAncestor` as you are traversing upward to parent class. `TObject` is the ultimate ancestor of all classes.

Comment: This feels wrong to me. I suspect your old delphi 6 exe was built using runtime packages, and your new one isn't. Or the package that you load is no longer built using runtime packages.

Comment: So to me I think the correct way to resolve the issue is to ensure that all modules (exe and all packages) are built to use runtime packages. That way there will be exactly one copy of each class in the process and type identity will work as expected.